# How to prevent concurrent access to a resource such as a USB device?

Tags: python, concurrency, locking, semaphore, superglobals

I would like to be able to use a USB device from several applications (for instance I run a Flask web application), making sure only one uses it at a time.

In my case I am using a relay to open / close a door. The door takes about 20 seconds to open. During that time the relay should not be activated, because this would lock the door in the middle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a lock file?

Comment: That would be nice and simple, although one would have to be careful to have a "safety trick" such as a timer to avoid the resource to be permanently locked because of an error.

Comment: Yes, that's true with any file locking mechanism. You could write the PID of the process in the lock file and check that it's still running when you try to acquire the lock, and implement an additional timeout mechanism if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of possible solutions.

The [posix_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/) or [sysv_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/) Python modules provide a named semaphore class. You can initialize a semaphore to 1 and have all your web processes acquire the semaphore while they send a command to the USB device.

A somewhat similar mechanism can be achieved using a file lock, maybe using [fcntl.lockf](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf).

Another completely different approach could be to put a new process between your web server processes and the USB API. This process exposes an API that receives requests from the web server workers and implicitly serializes those into the USB device by means of being a single threaded process.

Comment: I tried posix_ipc. I ran two instances of the program at the same time and it let me acquire the semaphore in both. Is that normal? In that case posix_ipc or sysv_ipc don't solve my problem. http://pastebin.com/RWHptWyd

Comment: I got `fcntl.lockf` working pretty easily. One should be careful though to not leave it permanently locked  in case of errors (this applies to most solutions).

Comment: You are not initializing the semaphore count to 1 when you create it third argument set to 1). It's odd that your test can acquire the semaphore, it seems to me with the code you pasted none of the instances should get through because the semaphore starts locked. Note that `aquire` decrements the count and `release` increments it.

Comment: They actually all get through. I'm not familiar with semaphores. I suppose that with an initial_value of 0, it would start "locked" and all `acquire`s would fail. I should use an initial value of 1. Is that what you mean? I also tried two consecutive calls to `acquire` (with initial_value=1) and they both succeeded. Something is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: My test appears to work fine, I could not run more than one of these at a time: http://pastebin.com/2d1v5Kth

Comment: Thanks. Both our tests are working. The problem comes from the fact at some point I got my semaphore value above 1. (If you want to know: Alarm released it, then Ctrl+C (SIGINT) released it again, which resulted to the value incremented twice.)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe another idea about how to tackle this with out using globals.

Why don't you write a small program for controlling your USB device. This script runs once (one instance) on your server and takes care of communicating with the device in the manner you need. It also takes care of concurrency.

Now communicate from your web application via pipes, sockets, whatever with this script, send commands to it and receive results from it.

Comment: How are "pipes" (I suppose as in UNIX shell pipes, as defined by the `pipes` module?) supposed to handle communication between processes started separately? For instance, I would start the USB controlling program with a startup script (`init.d`) and my web app runs with `mod_wsgi`.

Comment: There are all sorts of alternatives for this. Look for python broker on Google and you'll see some. One of the first results is rabbitmq, a popular one that works with Python.

Comment: Thanks! I chose the other answer as the accepted answer, but this means nothing. Yours is different and your idea is very nice as well. I might even prefer it because I might get other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variabale to your config (make sure its uppercase)

```
app.config['YOUR_GLOBAL'] = 'your global'
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/

Comment: Sorry, I just tried it and this doesn't work. My test was something as: if it doesn't exist, set global to False, else get value. The global never existed in each new session, so it's not shared by all sessions as I asked.